# Listview not showing scrollbar with custom UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, user-controls

When adding `downloadcontrols` to my `ObservableCollection<DownloadControl>`
they get displayed in the XAML's `ListView`. However, I'm unable to get the scrollbars to show up without setting explicit height. When i set the scrollbar to show. It appears on the left instead of right which makes me believe the binding is not in the correct place. But fail to get it to work properly. I use different `Listview`s with just labels and bindings and those behave as expected.

I've tried changing the layout using `gridview` and `gridviewcolumn` i've tried messing with the `DataTemplate`but this would result in databindings breaking on the `UserControl`.

My current xaml on my main window displaying the custom user controls in a listview

```xml
<ListView Name="ListViewDownloads" ItemsSource="{Binding DownloadControls}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="500"/>
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

```cs
public ObservableCollection<DownloadControl> DownloadControls
{
    get => (ObservableCollection<DownloadControl>)GetValue(DownloadControlsProperty);
    set => SetValue(DownloadControlsProperty, value);
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DownloadControls.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty DownloadControlsProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("DownloadControls", 
   typeof(ObservableCollection<DownloadControl>), typeof(MainWindow));
```

The user control DownloadControl

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="Robeats_Desktop.UserControls.DownloadControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Robeats_Desktop.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" MinWidth="150" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Source="{Binding Source}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Name="GridInfo">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" MaxWidth="250" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel>
                <Label>Title:</Label>
                <Label>Uploader:</Label>
                <Label>Duration:</Label>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <Label Content="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Uploader}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Duration}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" Background="Transparent" Name="ProgressBarDownload" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image: current result]
 this is the current result. The expected result is to have a scrollbar on the right when my elements are larger than the current height of the window.

The full source code: https://github.com/robeats-player/Robeats-Desktop

Comment: As a note, you won't usually bind an ItemsControl's ItemsSource to a collection of UI elements. The idea is to bind it to a collection of data items, and have a UI element in the ItemTemplate which binds to properties of the data item class.

Comment: @Clemens How'd you suggest on doing it then? The whole idea of the user control was reuseability but i'm not sure how else to achieve this when i'd have to bind just the data collection

Comment: ItemsControls have an ItemTemplate property. You would assign a DataTemplate that contains your UserControl. The control would have bindable properties which bind to the properties of the data item. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Comment: If you *really* need a ListView, the DataTemplate would have to be put in the CellTemplate of a GridViewColumn.

Comment: I dont *really* need one, I'm just at a loss what other controls could be used for this. On a side note: I did try using the datatemplate but that caused my bindings to break. I could reproduce it if needed.

Comment: That's because you've explicitly set the UserControl's DataContext to `this`. That is a common mistake, but you must not do that. Instead, use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}` for the Bindings in the UserControl's XAML.

Comment: I've tried what you said. Removed the datacontext (it was indeed set to itself) added `ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:DownloadControl}}"` am i missing anything else? It still doesn't add any scrollbars.

Comment: As said, I mean the Bindings in the UserControl's XAML, e.g. `<Label Content="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />`. And all this doesn't refer to the scrollbars. It's just about how to properly write a UserControl and use it in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl.